# Why is my photo rotating the wrong way when I transform in CSS?

Tags: html, css, transform

I wanted to do a scrapbook-style website but why is the windmill flower rotating in an odd way? It rotates on a different point and not one the center of the photo, even thought the photo is 1x1. I wanted it to rotate like an actual windmill. Any ideas?

```
<style>
body {
overflow-x: hidden;
}

div.b {
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
left: 700px;
top: -300px;

animation: rotation 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotation { 
from { 
tranform: rotate(0deg); 
} 
to { 
transform: rotate(360deg); 
} }
```

Comment: Your Q is not clear. Please also add your HTML (full snippet)

Comment: You need to specify `transform-origin`.

Comment: That's because you've already translated the element from the origin. You can fix this by changing the `transform-origin` that offsets the left and top values.

Comment: Oh I see!! Thank you for your help!